# Selecting An Element In Web Browser VB

Tags: vb.net

```
<td class="data-display-field" width="20%" valign="top">
  <table class="printtotal" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" ><tbody>
    <tr class="list-row">
      <td class="data-display-field" width="60%" style="font-weight: bold" align="center" colspan="2">Order Totals</td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="list-row">
      <td class="data-display-field" width="60%" align="right" >Items total:</td>
      <td class="data-display-field" width="40%" align="right" >

£323.36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list-row">
      <td class="data-display-field" width="60%" align="right" >Delivery total:</td>
      <td class="data-display-field" width="40%" align="right" >

£7.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list-row">
      <td class="data-display-field" style="color: #CC0000" width="60%" align="right" >Refund(s) total:</td>
      <td class="data-display-field" style="color: #CC0000" width="40%" align="right" >(

£330.36)</td>
    </tr>
```

How would I be able to make my web browser in VB select the money amount after "Refund(s) total:", I don't know how to do it as they all have the same class

Answer (score 0):

you may use a unique id for elements like

```
<td id="id001"></td>
```

and with jquery you nay select id like this

```
$('#id001')
```

any reason that you are not using id?

Comment: There is no ID, this is the Amazon web page and I am wanting to pull information off that page